# difference between RES and %MEM?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I need to know the exact difference between the following two params:

```
HOST                PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  **RES**  SHR S %CPU **%MEM**    TIME+  COMMAND

Lx230 (primary)   20836 app   18   0 6095m **2.0g**   16m S   1.3    **7.5** 232:18.04 java

Lx231 (secondary) 16352 app   23   0 5901m 626m  16m S  0.7  2.2  56:44.35 java
```

As I see RES is 2gb, %MEM is 7.5, Whats does it mean? Is it my application occupied 2gb of memory at present?  I mean does it occupied 2gb of heap space? or it's occupied 7.5% of heap space?

Comment: did you try the manual page `man top` - `%MEM --  Memory Usage (RES) A task's currently used share of available physical memory.`, `RES -- resident memory size - the non-swapped physical memory a task has used`.

Comment: yeah i read that, still i am not exactly getting whats the non swapped memory? how to co relate the heap memory with it?

Comment: VIRT == all memory allocated to process (heap + code) - some may be swapped out. RES == memory currently swapped in (heap + code). %MEM - this is the RES value as a percent of overall physical memory.